# update the values of joined table when insert data into tables that i used to create the joined table

Tags: mysql

I have created two tables **employees_tab**  and **devices_tab** in MySQL work bench.

**Devices_tab**

```
Serial_No   Device_ID   Device_Name           Level
1            2001       Desktop Computer         1
2            2001       Laptop                   2
3            2001       Desktop Computer         3
```

**employees_tab**

```
Employee_ID Employee_Name   Designation          Password         Level

1001        Nimal           Manager             698d51a19d8a1211    1
1002        Kamal           Accountant          2c0343a2395834dd    2
1003        Sunil           Trainee             f762a2aaa148d556bd  3
```

Now I need to take all devices which have according to level for each employee and create a new table. Also in each time that I insert new user to the employee table new table should be updated with that value. 
How do i do that?
I use SQL joins. But i can't update that in each time the new table with using old tables

Comment: Think you would be best using triggers to do this. A trigger is a (normally small) function that is executed when a record is added / updated / deleted from a table

Answer (score 0):

```html
INSERT INTO table3(Device_Name,Employee_Name,Level)
SELECT t1.Device_Name,t2.Employee_Name,t2.Level
FROM Devices_tab t1
LEFT JOIN employees_tab t2 ON t1.Level=t2.Level
```

Try This Code.Not sure but you try give a idea.